# Query to delete data from table names listed in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database "Student" which contains about 20 tables. 
one of the tables is "Columns" which stores all the column names in "Column_Names" column from all the tables present in "Student" database. This table also stores table names in "Table_Names" column

Now, I want to write a query which queries "Columns" table and looks for "Column_Name" with last four characters as "test". Here is my query for that:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Students.Columns
  WHERE Column_Name Like '%test'
```

Now I want to write a delete query which would delete data from all the tables listed in "Table_Names" column in the above query output where, columns with last four characters "test" has "del" as data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop over each entry, build a dynamic query, and execute it using sp_executesql.  This should work (untested):

```
SELECT *
Into #Temp
  FROM Students.Columns
  WHERE Column_Name Like '%test'

Declare @Column_Name nvarchar(max)
Declare @Table_Name nvarchar(max)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
Begin
  Select Top 1 @Column_Name = Column_Name, @Table_Name = Table_Name From #Temp
  Set @Sql = N'DELETE FROM ' + @Table_Name + N' WHERE ' + @Column_Name + N' = @delete_key'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, N'@delete_key nvarchar(max)', @delete_key = N'del'

  Delete #Temp Where Column_Name = @Column_Name AND Table_Name = @TableName
End
```

Comment: 'del' is not the Column Name 'del' is the data in columns. Columns with 'del' as data needs to be deleted

Comment: I am reading it wrong, my mistake. However, the data is not being deleted. I opened of of the tables with last four characters of column name = 'text' that has 'del' as data in that column, it was still present. Is this only deleting it in #Temp table and not the originals?

Comment: Was that 'text' or 'test' in your last comment?  You may want to perform some debug output to see what the initial `#Temp` table contains, and also just before the `EXECUTE sp_executesql` to see what values are used for the @Column_Name and @Table_Name variables

Comment: My bad, I setup the parameters incorrectly - try the updated SQL code.

Comment: I get an "Incorrect syntax near '+'." on:           N'DELETE FROM ' + (at)TABLE_NAME + N' WHERE ' + (at)COLUMN_NAME + N' = (at)delete_key',

Comment: Hmm, try creating the SQL string before the execution (as updated again)